# zsh calling a function

Tags: function, zsh

I'm trying to call up a function in zsh script, up to now without success.

I store my functions in a directory ~/zz_functions and scripts in ~/zz_scripts

~/zz_functions has been added to fpath

```
    fpath=($fpath ~/zz_functions) 
    echo $fpath proved
```

~/zz_scripts had been added to path variable

one poc function is called 'hello'

`printf 'Hello world.\n`'

From the cli the hello function works returning hello world ==>> proving it works

I want to call the function from within a script called s2.sh
'''

```
#! usr/bin/zsh
hello
```

this is the result

```
──(rootGRINIUS-INC-61S7CT)-[~]
└─# zsh ~/zz_scripts/s2.sh
/root/zz_scripts/s2.sh:2: command not found: hello
```

Why does "hello" work on cli and not within a script?
I'm sure its an obvious reason but its escaped me!

Please don't tell me of the dangers of using root. I know and take precautions.

Thanks

Comment: In your script, the invocation of `hello` is the first statement after the #! line. I don't see that you would set `fpath` inside your script. You also did not show that you would have exported `FPATH`, which would be an alternative way to set the function path for your script. You can verify this by putting a `echo $FPATH` (or `echo $fpath[*]`  if you prefer) before invoking _hello_.

Comment: What does it give?

Comment: echo $FPATH gives:-

'/root/zz_functions:/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions:/usr/share/zsh/vendor-functions:/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions:/usr/share/zsh/functions/Calen .....'

All my pre-defined functions work ok on cl but not within a script.

I've tried defining fpath and FPATH within the script with no effect.
'fpath=( ~/zz_functions/ "${fpath[@]}" )
FPATH=~/zz_functions:$FPATH'

What does work is
 'autoload -Uz hello'
This however seems to defeat the benefit of having functions if you have to autoload them for each script.

Comment: Sorry for the format - I need to get around MD

Comment: _autoload_ basically say: "load this function only if it is actually called", and `fpath`/`FPATH` defines the places where the function is searched in this case. If you want to load the functions unconditionally (i.e. irrespective of whether or not they are invoked in your script), this is the wrong mechanism anyway. In this case you would simply use `source` or `.`.

Comment: Another approach you may consider is to put your function definitions into `.zshenv`. They woul then be loaded automatically. Since the directory where zsh searches for this file, can be explicitly specified by the variable `ZDOTDIR` , you can even keep the function definitions for separated projects / use cases apart.

Comment: so in my case to load the functions using 'source'     '. ~/zz_functions'  This doesn't have any effect on the calling functions.  I'd prefer not to use .zshenv.

Comment: I think this is the approach I would also choose. It makes the definition point of the function explicitly visible, which is also benefical for code maintenance.

Comment: Still no joy using source in script.  ` ~/zz_functions`

Comment: Then ask a new question: Show a minimal reproducible example, which demonstrates that despite of sourcing the file, the functions are not available. If we can't reproduce what you are doing, we can't tell you where you made a mistake.

Comment: OK. thanks for you help.